# Android Picasso cloned but can't run the sample project, no gradle files found

Tags: android, git, android-library, picasso, square

I have cloned the Square/Picasso Github repo, however, I did not find any Gradle files and therefore I am still stuck figuring out how to use the library and run the sample app as well. I want to use the code instead of the jar because I have few modifications I need in the library to use it.

Comment: Why not just copy the [main src](https://github.com/square/picasso/tree/master/picasso/src) files with your changes to your src folder? Or download the library, make the changes, build your changes and use that build

Comment: I want to keep it out of the code, and use it as a module instead. I don't know what I am missing, but I am still trying to have the code as a module and I can't do that since Android Studio keeps saying that it's not a Gradle project..

Comment: That's because Picasso *isn't* a Gradle project. It's a Maven project. Like I said, you could download the library, make your changes and build your own special .jar. Use `mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true` then check picasso/target for the .jar file

Comment: Thanks bro, that made things clear. you can put it as an answer for me to accept :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up from my comments in your question, if you want to use picasso with your changes, what you'll need to do is clone [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), make your changes to the source, then run a Maven package task, if you have Maven:

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

If the build is successful, you will find your .jar file to use as a library, with all your changes, in directory `picasso/target`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Android Studio. Inside your build.gradle file, there is a dependencies section. Simply add the following to the list of dependencies

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

And then sync your project. The Picasso library will be added to your project.

Answer (score 0):

As Bidhan points out, in the Readme file you can find the info

Using **Gradle**:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

or **Maven**:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.picasso</groupId>
  <artifactId>picasso</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `build.gradle` dependencies section:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.1'
```